# Any Open Source Databases storing Finger Prints and Iris?

Tags: biometrics

Are there any free open sourced databases online that i can download finger print images and iris images as testing data for purposes of my final year project? Looking into bio-metrics?

Comment: Asking for tool/product recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find many biometric databases at the [NIST](https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/image-group/resources/biometric-special-databases-and-software) (National Institute of Standards and Technology) website.

[Biometrics Ideal Test](http://biometrics.idealtest.org/) offers several databases for different biometric characteristics. Among those are very large datasets (20.000 iris images from 1000 subjects and 20.000 fingerprint images from 500 subjects).

[IIT Delhi iris database](http://www4.comp.polyu.edu.hk/~csajaykr/IITD/Database_Iris.htm) has some high quality iris images.

[UBIRIS](http://iris.di.ubi.pt/) is an iris database with noisy data.

[This article](https://www.ijert.org/view-pdf/376/comparative-study-of-iris-databases-and-ubiris-database-for-iris-recognition-methods-for-non-cooperative-environment) ("Comparative Study of Iris Databases and UBIRIS Database for Iris Recognition Methods for Non-Cooperative Environment"), may also be of interest for you.

Others can be easily found via a Google search. The available databases are usually free to use (in some cases you might have to register and be validated as a student/researcher). When you publish, it is courteous to make an acknowledgement/citation about the dataset you used - many will even provide a BibTex entry for your convenience.

Comment: Please don't answer expressly off-topic questions. This isn't the place for product/service recommendations.

Comment: GloriaVictis - Thank you so much :P